# Can an iframe behave as mobile browser?

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, iframe, browser

I'm working on a school project where I need an iframe to behave as an mobile browser.
So far I have an iPhone as background-image and an iframe positioned according to the iPhones screen, but when I load the page it loads the desktop version of the page.

How do I do to load the mobile version of the page. Also is there a possibility to use meta viewport?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to preserve responsive design in mobile browser's iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223469/how-to-preserve-responsive-design-in-mobile-browsers-iframe)

Comment: Take a look on the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17223671/871672

Answer (score 0):

If you're mobile site has a dedicated url (m.mysite.com) just point your iframe to that. Granted, I assume you would have thought of that.

The other case, of some sort of detection and a responsive design, it depends one what your detection method is. If you're sniffing user agents, I haven't been able to find anyway to change the user agent of just an iframe.

If you're using some other check to render the mobile version, you just need that to be present in the iframe, assuming that's possible.

Also, the viewport meta tag will tell a page how to render, but can't force it to switch between versions of your site.