# How to preserve responsive design in mobile browser's iframe?

Tags: html, css, mobile, iframe, responsive-design

I would like to load a responsive design website in an iframe as one of my website's pages. However, when it's loaded in the iframe, the site loses its responsiveness.

Using Mashable.com as an example (which is built in responsive design)- my code looks like this:

```
<body>
    <style>
    body {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#252525;}
    #iframe {position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;}
    </style>

    <iframe id="iframe" name="iframe1" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://mashable.com"></iframe>
</body>
```

If you go to mashable.com on your phone, you'll see the responsive design in action. However, if you visit the page above on your phone, mashable's responsive design isn't functioning.

Does anyone know how to load a web page in a div and keep its responsive design?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps it is better to open it in a new tab since if you load a bunch of iframes on your own page, you are also making the user download extra stuff from the other websites. Also this cannot be reproduced in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2tmzR/ maybe because they are doing something similar to the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the **meta tag** "*viewport*" to the head of your page to tell the **mobile browser** not scale the page. 
Safari on the desktop already respects the responsive design of the iframe content by default.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Open [this JSBin link](http://jsbin.com/eyalos/1) on your mobile to test ***with*** the meta tag and the [following link](http://jsbin.com/eyalos/3/) ***without*** the meta tag. To edit open this [JSBin page](http://jsbin.com/eyalos/1/edit).

NB. Tested on iPhone 5 (iOS6) and Safari 6.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use jquery:

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
    var
    $this       = $(this),
    proportion  = $this.data( 'proportion' ),
     w           = $this.attr('width'),
   actual_w    = $this.width();

    if ( ! proportion )
    {
        proportion = $this.attr('height') / w;
        $this.data( 'proportion', proportion );
    }

    if ( actual_w != w )
    {
         $this.css( 'height', Math.round( actual_w * proportion ) + 'px' );
    }
});
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/aarongustafson/1313517